# Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_candidate_photo()

Tags: php, wordpress

I activated wp-job-manager plugin on jobiffy themes when I activated a widget name Resume Manager then show this error what can i do?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_candidate_photo() in
>   /home/techmuub/jobsvide/wp-content/themes/jobify/inc/integrations/wp-job-manager/widgets/class-widget-job-company-logo.php
>   on line 72

documentation: https://wpjobmanager.com/document/resume-manager-template-tags/#section-3

```
<?php
/**
 * Job/Resume: Logo
 *
 * @since Jobify 1.6.0
 */
class Jobify_Widget_Job_Company_Logo extends Jobify_Widget {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->widget_cssclass    = 'jobify_widget_job_company_logo';
        $this->widget_description = __( 'Display the company logo or resume picture', 'jobify' );
        $this->widget_id          = 'jobify_widget_job_company_logo';
        $this->widget_name        = __( 'Jobify - Job/Resume: Logo', 'jobify' );
        $this->settings           = array(
            'title' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => '',
                'label' => __( 'Title:', 'jobify' )
            )
        );

        $this->settings = jobify_rcp_subscription_selector( $this->settings );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * widget function.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget
     * @access public
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     * @return void
     */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( $this->get_cached_widget( $args ) )
            return;

        global $wp_embed;

        ob_start();

        extract( $args );

        global $post;

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', isset ( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ? $instance[ 'title' ] : '', $instance, $this->id_base );

        echo $before_widget;
        ?>

        <?php if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>

        <?php if ( 'job_listing' == get_post_type() ) : ?>

            <?php
                if ( class_exists( 'Astoundify_Job_Manager_Companies' ) && '' != get_the_company_name() ) :
                    $companies   = Astoundify_Job_Manager_Companies::instance();
                    $company_url = esc_url( $companies->company_url( get_the_company_name() ) );
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $company_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_company_logo(); ?></a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php the_company_logo(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php the_candidate_photo( 'large' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        echo $after_widget;

        $content = apply_filters( 'jobify_widget_job_company_logo', ob_get_clean(), $instance, $args );

        echo $content;

        $this->cache_widget( $args, $content );
    }
}
```

Comment: Chk the_candidate_photo function in yur helper files either exist or not

Answer (score 0):

According to the GitHub repo of this plugin (https://github.com/Automattic/WP-Job-Manager/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=the_candidate_photo) the function the_candidate_photo doesn't exist.